# Python webscraping for lists of company names and details using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I just started learning Python and made a script that scrapes a corporate directory 
**https://www.sccci.org.sg/en/directory/corporate/members**

So far it gets all the company names and their details under one category page (although i do intend on making it automatically get the details of the other pages too in the future) and writes them into a text file.

**However the code uses a lot of nested loops and i am looking to see if there is a better way to code it in terms of efficiency and good practice.**

Here is the code:

```
#Author: James
#Date: 9/11/2017
#nlist stores company names
#detlist stores the details
#finlist stores the href links required to scrape the subsites of SCCCI
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
check = False
finlist = []
nlist = []
detlist = []
r = requests.get("https://www.sccci.org.sg/en/directory/corporate/members?ind=150")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
#finds all the links in the html class "listing" and store them in "finlist"
for items in soup.findAll("div", {"class" : "listing"}):
    for a in items.findAll("ol"):
        for b in a.findAll("a"):
            finlist.append("https://www.sccci.org.sg" + b.get("href"))
#enters each site in finlist and gets the company name found in "member-name"
for record in finlist:
    print("Entering " + record + "...")
    lr = requests.get(record)
    lsoup = BeautifulSoup(lr.content, "html.parser")
    for o in lsoup.findAll(["span"], {"class" : "member-name"}):
        nlist.append(o.get_text("\n",strip=True))
    for o in lsoup.findAll("div", {"class" : "member-info hidden"}):
        detlist.append(o.get_text("\n",strip=True))
    #this loops checks for any additional pages in the link and searches though the additional sites for names and details too
    for j in lsoup.findAll("li", {"class" : "pager-item"}):
        for b in j.findAll("a"):
            print(" Entering https://www.sccci.org.sg" + b.get("href") + "...")
            mR = requests.get("https://www.sccci.org.sg" + b.get("href"))
            mSoup = BeautifulSoup(mR.content, "html.parser")
            for soups in mSoup.findAll("span", {"class" : "member-name"}):
                nlist.append(soups.get_text("\n",strip=True))
            for soups in mSoup.findAll("div", {"class" : "member-info hidden"}):
                detlist.append(soups.get_text("\n",strip=True))

# Request process end -- File dump process start --

print("Start file dump...")
text_file = open("debug.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8")
#combines the namelist and detaillist into the finalList
finalList = [j for i in zip(nlist,detlist) for j in i]
for zippy in finalList:
    zippy = zippy.replace("                                    "," ")
    zipstring = str(zippy)
    text_file.write(zipstring + "\n\n")
text_file.close()
text_file_names = open("cnames.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8")
count = 0
for names in nlist:
    count+= 1
    names = str(names)
    text_file_names.write(str(count) + " | " + names + "\n")
text_file_names.close()
text_file_pnames = open("names.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8")
for pnames in nlist:
    pnames = str(pnames)
    text_file_pnames.write(pnames + "\n")
text_file_pnames.close()
finalitem = len(finalList)/2
print("Done | " + str(finalitem) + " items")
print("Files generated: names.txt | debug.txt | cnames.txt")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like you are creating a kind of a crawler. To improve on performance, you can use a [`Session`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects) object. It will utilize the underlying TCP connection, making the script run faster.

You can also use `BeautifulSoup`'s `SoupStrainer` to only parse the `listing` tag. This way, your crawler won't have to go through each and every line of the HTML document.

Additionally on perfomance, you can use the `lxml` parser which happens to be faster than `html.parser`.

You seem to be using the base link quite often, move it into a constant and add `href` tags to it as needed.

As an example, the way you are filling up your `finlist` can be written as such.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer

URL = 'https://www.sccci.org.sg'
session = requests.Session()

response = session.get(URL + '/en/directory/corporate/members?ind=150')
strainer = SoupStrainer(class_='listing')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml', parse_only=strainer)
listing_links = [URL + link['href'] for link in soup.select('ol[start] a[href]')]
```

Note that I have used all of the above and CSS selectors resulting in reducing the amount of `for` loops to just one. Populating `finlist` takes about 2 seconds on my machine.

Staying on `finlist`, it's not a particularly descriptive variable name. Perhaps something like `listing_links` would be better?

I can't go through the rest of the crawler as I am short on time, but for file operations, use the `with` statement. It will ensure the file is closed, even if an error occurs.
Example usage:

```
foo = '1234'
with open('bar.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(foo)
```

Answer (score 4):

Lukasz has already pinpointed multiple issues, but if we were to talk specifically about removing the nested loops with something less nested, I would look into [CSS selectors](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) and [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

For instance, the following part:

```
for items in soup.findAll("div", {"class" : "listing"}):
    for a in items.findAll("ol"):
        for b in a.findAll("a"):
            finlist.append("https://www.sccci.org.sg" + b.get("href"))
```

can be replaced with:

```
finlist = ["https://www.sccci.org.sg" + a.get("href")
           for a in soup.select(".listing ol a")]
```